# How to save log file from pulp , log including algorithms used by the solver?

Tags: pulp, cbc

How to save log file from pulp , log including algorithms used by the solver  ?

while this is printed in the python IDE console, looking to save it as a txt file .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the logPath argument:

```
prob.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=1,logPath="info.log")
```

More information can be found here:

https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/technical/solvers.html#pulp.apis.COIN_CMD

Comment: Any idea wat it could be for xpress pulp interface?